# How can I log the day used for local notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, notifications

I'm trying to log the day but not the date that my notification will fire at.

say I have this code that I need it to fire on Sunday, here is what I tried and what came out after that:

```
-(void) Sunday {   // 9th Notification Every 1:35

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];

NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSWeekCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

components.weekday = 1;
components.hour   = 22;
components.minute = 38;
components.second = 25;

NSDate *fire = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
NSLog(@"The Fire day is:: %@", fire);

UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc]  init] ;
if (notif == nil)
    return;

notif.fireDate = fire;
notif.repeatInterval= NSWeekCalendarUnit ;
notif.soundName = @"ring.wav";
notif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"THANKS for Your HELP :)"] ;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif] ;
}
```

and the log shows:

```
2014-01-19 22:37:45.470 daily notification test[15595:c07] The Fire day is:: 0001-01-21 22:38:25 +0000
```

I'm just trying to fire a notification every specific day of the week regardless of the month and the year.. but it only works with me when defining the hour only and using the `NSHourCalendarUnit`.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear to not be working because you aren't setting the year, so it's defaulting to 0001. Don't just take `NSWeekCalendarUnit` from the current date, take the year too.

Comment: Although I need it without the month and the year, however, I did try that and still not working. It would show the year 2014 and todays date! I need it to work on any day of the week I specify it, regardless of the date.

Comment: You need to set the correct first date. You can't start with a date in the past. Then it will repeat after the first fire.

Comment: Here is what I got when I tried the `NSYearCalendarUnit` this output `2014-01-20 01:09:17.187 daily notification test[16302:c07] The Fire day is:: 2014-01-20 01:08:45 +0000` but I still don't see any notification showing up on the simulator! why?

Comment: Try creating the fire date with `dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5` as a sanity check (so no date components used).

Comment: I actually did a different sanity check using `NSHourCalendarUnit` and it works greatly on the hour regardless of the day!! So it has to be something wrong with the `NSWeekCalendarUnits` or the day setting.

Comment: In your test, you allow the notification to fire at the first date, then change the device time so it can fire a 'week' later?